# Why static methods can't call non-static methods directly?

Tags: static

I don't understand why most programming language don't allow developers/users to call non-static method from static method directly? What is the reason behind it?

p.s. I know, you can create object and call non-static method from static method.

Comment: The question is equivalent to "Why can't I accelerate without a car"

Comment: Note: I understand the other question is about data, but the answers are perfectly valid for this question and explain it well.

Comment: There is no instance to pass to the method for it to use as `this`

Comment: "most" programming languages don't allow it?  Okay, please please please show me one that does.

Comment: @MikeNakis PHP, of course :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because a static field/method--by definition--is not tied to any single object/instance of the class, while a non-static field/method always refers to an actual object/instance in some way.

Since that probably sounded too vague/abstract to answer the question, and this kind of confusion usually stems from a misunderstanding of what static actually means, let's make this concrete with some C++-like pseudocode:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static int a() { return 2; }
    int b()        { return d_x; }
    Foo(int x)     { d_x = x; }
private:
    int d_x;
}
```

The static method `a` is not tied to any particular instance of `Foo`, meaning it can be called from anywhere, whether or not you have an actual `Foo` object. In C++ you'd simply write `Foo::a()`, and it would always return 2.

The non-static method `b` *is* tied to a single instance of `Foo`. Because it simply returns the int inside a given `Foo` object, it doesn't make any sense to try calling `b()` without a specific `Foo` object. What would you expect it to return if it didn't have a `Foo`? So `Foo f; f.b();` makes sense but `Foo::b()` does not.

If I tried to make a() call b(), then whenever I called a() without an actual instance of `Foo`, I'd also be calling b() without an actual instance of `Foo`, so now a() doesn't make sense either.

Essentially, the two methods are implemented something like this:

```
namespace Foo {
    int a() {
        return 2;
    }
    int b(Foo* this) {
        return this->x;
    }
};
```

When you look at the methods this way, it's fairly obvious why b() can call a() but not the other way around: a() simply doesn't have a `Foo*` lying around to give to b().

---

Incidentally, you *can* "work around" this limitation by writing a static method that takes an actual `Foo` object and then calls non-static methods on that `Foo` object. But that's usually a code smell indicating that you have static methods which shouldn't be static or non-static method that should be static, or a class that's trying to do too many things at once.

Answer (score 1):

Because all static things are not related to any object, but they are related to a class. So all objects of same class will access same static methods.

On the other hand, non static methods are attached to a particular object of a class.

You can call static methods without creating any object of a class, but that is not the case with non static methods.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat Tongue-in-cheek... Or at least this is the functional perspective on methods...

There is no such thing called "method"

```
class Apple
{
 ...
public void Eat()
{
    this.weight --;
}
public static Apple ChangeColor(Apple apple)
{
    apple.color = Color.GetRandomColor();
}
}
```

The example above defines a class with two methods one static and one isn't.
The second is actually a **function** that receives a single parameter of the Apple type and changes it's color. The first is also a **function** that **implicitly** receives a parameter called `this` and decreases it's weight.

That's basically the idea behind a 'member function' / 'member method'. It receives an implicit first parameter of the type of the class.

so doing this: `Apple.Eat()` doesn't make sense, there are too few parameters (Apple is the class name here).

while this does:

```
Apple x = new Apple();
x.eat()
```

That 'implicit first parameter' of 'member methods' in OOP languages also has a special feature around it. If a member method is virtual (language specific) then the method will be **dynamically invoked** based on the type of that parameter.

[Dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) or dynamic invocation, is something similar to method overloads - that is deciding which method to call based on compile time type, except it happens at **runtime**.

Some programming languages allow doing this on all parameters of a function - this is called  [Multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)

Though most OOP languages allow this only for the 'first implicit parameter' of 'member methods' - this is called virtual methods, Polymorphism and [single dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#Single_and_multiple_dispatch).

---

By the way...
There is a whole design pattern called [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) solely to allow some sort of Multiple dispatch to languages that don't have the feature